# Why do magnetometer values change when I move PCB?

Tags: c, imu, magnetometer, compass, sensor-fusion

I have an [MPU9250](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf) on my PCB and I use an AHRS system with a Madgwick filter to get yaw angle. But for some reason - I can't get normal Euler angles ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70242354/why-does-yaw-angle-goes-away-when-i-move-controller)). But I guess, I understood why. When I move PCB without rotating it - magnetometer values change rapidly. Like that:
[image]
I show raw values in the chart, but with calibrated values - the result is the same.
I use this code to work with *MPU9250* https://github.com/sonphambk/MPU9250/blob/master/Src/IMU/MPU9250.c.
Why do magnetometer values change if I move PCB without rotating it?

Comment: What is the conversion of your units to magnetic field values ? If the change is on the order of 1 µT, it could be well down to small unintentional rotations. Also note that you might move the board closer/further from magnetic objects like screwdrivers, bolts, computers, belts, table legs..

Comment: thanks for the replies, but this is a little weird. I have a magnet that I can bring to the magnetometer. And the magnetometer itself starts to change values only if I bring the magnet close enough. Yes, I have various environment on my desk, but it's not very close to the pcb. I didn't think it could have such a strong impact.

Comment: Magnetometers will pick up ambient (non-Earth) magnetic fields from the local environment.  These can often change heavily over cm to meters (especially indoors, around ferrous materials, or around electrical lines/equipment) so I wouldn't expect particularly high accuracy from a magnetometer except in controlled conditions.  See e.g. what's needed to [ensure compass accuracy in marine and aviation applications](https://www.google.com/search?q=considerations+for+compass+mounting+aircraft+ship).

Comment: If you aren't rotating it any direction (yaw, pitch, or roll) then it is likely some other object or power source interfering with it. I have seen people get surprised when their wedding ring or steel table deflects a compass before because they didn't think about what those things were made of. In a house there are hundereds of objects that can deflect a compass. And their are tons of power sources such as lights and computers than can influence a magenetometer.